# How to clone an external database in a internal SQLite database? (Android)

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

Is there a direct way to clone an external database in an internal database?

I have a code to retrieve the data from external database using HttpPost.

Another thing, a field in the table of my database stores the url to images within my server, is there a way to download these images by url and save on Android?

And copy-protect the database and images?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to 1) copy-protect the data and 2) copy it?

Comment: I have an external DB in my webserver.
What I want is:

1) Copy DB from Webserver to SQLite DB in Android (clone).
2) Download and store de images in Android (a field in the table of my database stores the url to images).
3) Protect the DB and images.